# Regex to find characters not having a certain character before them

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have these strings in Javascript:

```
var string1 = '#23 the id of this report is \\# 23';
var string2 = '# \\# \\# # \\\\# #';
```

I want to do a `.replace()` that replaces **all** `#` **with no** `\\` **before them** with `\\#`, but can't write the correct regex.

Result for `string2` should be `\\# \\# \\# \\# \\\\# \\#`

Any thoughts?

## Update

**Working solutions:**

- [torazaburo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/663031/torazaburo)'s [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36980500/4761178)
- [gurvinder372](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1984039/gurvinder372)'s [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36979635/4761178)

Comment: By `\\\` do you mean two physical backslashes, or one?

Comment: Why do you need this ?

Comment: Some weird task at my work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target hash marks with no backslashes before them by first matching  hash marks **with** backslashes before them, then as an alternative (using the alternation operator, also known as the pipe, `|`) try a hash mark by itself, which will therefore match hash marks **with no** backslash before it, and replacing in either case with `\#`:

```js
var string2       = '# \\# \\# # \\\\# #';
var maybe_escaped = /\\#|#/g;
var result        = string2.replace(maybe_escaped, '\\#');

document.getElementById('result').textContent = JSON.stringify(result);
```

```html
<div id='result' style="font-family: monospace; "></div>
```

An alternative approach is just to use the following regexp, although the one above might be considered to better embody the negative look-behind nature of the problem and is more generalizable.

```
/\\?#/
```

Comment: `# \\# \\# # \\\\# #` is the correct string to account for. '\\' refers to a single escaped backslash as you've assumed. The question is how to target hashtags with no backslashes before them (and of course replace them with `\\#`).

Comment: That's it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this replacer function

```
 .replace(/[\\]{0,1}#/g, "\\#")
```

**DEMO**

```js
var string1 = '#23 the id of this report is \\# 23';
alert(string1.replace(/[\\]{0,1}#/g, "\\#"));
var string2 = '# \\# \\\# \# \\\\# #';
alert(string2.replace(/[\\]{0,1}#/g, "\\#"));
var string3 = '# \\# \\# # \\\\# #';
alert(string3.replace(/[\\]{0,1}#/g, "\\#"));
```

Comment: This works, but I want to do this by pure regex only and nothing else. +1 though.

Comment: You're returning the same thing in both branches of the `if` statement? How is `[\\]` different from \\? How is `[\\]{0,1}` different from `[\\]?`? How is either different from `\\?`?

Comment: @torazaburo got it! Updating the code, it was so simple :) Thanks for pointing out

Comment: @RamtinSoltani check now with pure regex

Comment: It gives this result `\\# \\\# \\\# \\# \\\\\# \\#` when tested on `# \\# \\# # \\\\# #`

Comment: @RamtinSoltani what should it give instead? does `\\` mean double backslash in the final string or single one?

Comment: This is the desired output `\\# \\# \\# \\# \\\\# \\#` as in not escaped.

Comment: @RamtinSoltani that is precisely the output I get when I run the code. Can you test the example attached again?

Comment: This is correct too. Already accepted @torazaburo 's solution but thanks for the answer.

Comment: @RamtinSoltani No worries, glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

This regex seems to work

```
(\\\\?)?#
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xZ0dJ5/1)**

*NOTE* :- I am assuming that `\#` will be replaced as `\\#`. If you want output to be `\\\#`, you can then use

```
(\\\\)?#
```

Comment: I have updated the given strings. Don't mind the hashtags with odd backslashes. This answer works, but it also replaces `\\#` with `\\#`. What would be the regex that in this given string `# \\# \\# # \\\\# #` only targets the hashtags with no two or more backslashes?

Comment: @RamtinSoltani its an alternative to lookbehinds as javascript does not support lookbehinds..otherwise it would be much easier

Comment: @RamtinSoltani till I understood you are talking about `\#` should be replaced to `\\#`?

Comment: This raw data `# \\# \\# # \\\\# #` to be `\\# \\# \\# \\# \\\\# \\#` (not literal backslashes, two means one escaped backslash)